# How put uncertainty shading on a linear fit

Tags: statistics

I have a scatter plot and only my y values have uncertainty.

I obtained a linear fit to my data (using `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize`).

[image]

I also have the 1 sigma uncertainty for the gradient and the intercept of the linear fit:

Gradient: -4.304e-06 +- 3.908e-06
Intercept: 0.068 +- 0.005

But I want to put some kind of uncertainty shading on my linear fit so i can visualize the uncertainty on the linear fit?

To do this, I think I need to considered the covariance between the gradient and intercept parameters, but I'm not certain. [The top answer on this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70629/calculate-uncertainty-of-linear-regression-slope-based-on-data-uncertainty) gives a formula for the interdependence of gradient and intercept:

[image]

To get my visualization, would I just sample from this ring and plot many linear fits on my plot to shade an uncertainty region?